# Create a genet class from a frequency matrix in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I try to use the "freq2genet" method to create a "genet" class in R with package "adegenet". But once I call the method with my data set in which gene frequencies are stored, an error occurs that 'type'(character) parameters are incorrect. It still occurs after I use "as.data.frame".

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You need to change the format of your data not the type of your data. Maybe correcting the parameters from character to logical would do. Did you look it up on the manual?

Comment: How does your data differ from that of an example of `freq2genet` or any other working example?

Comment: @Llopis How to do that?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik there is no example to refer to for freq2genet...

Comment: At this point, I will ask for a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object passed to `freq2genet` should be a data.frame, where rows are observations (populations) and columns are allele frequencies. This is the data structure from example of `ade4:::chevaine`. Whatever is different from this might be a reason for your error.

```
> head(chevaine$tab)
    PGM-2*.090 PGM-2*.098 PGM-2*.100 IDHP-1*.100 IDHP-1*.145 EST-2*.098 EST-2*.100 G3PDH*.085 G3PDH*.100
P01      0.017      0.150      0.833       1.000       0.000      0.300      0.700      0.217      0.783
P02      0.083      0.216      0.701       1.000       0.000      0.300      0.700      0.167      0.833
P03      0.107      0.179      0.714       0.982       0.018      0.250      0.750      0.179      0.821
P04      0.067      0.200      0.733       1.000       0.000      0.467      0.533      0.217      0.783
P05      0.103      0.190      0.707       1.000       0.000      0.362      0.638      0.103      0.897
P06      0.179      0.125      0.696       0.981       0.019      0.250      0.750      0.154      0.846

> str(freq2genet(chevaine$tab))
List of 8
 $ tab       :'data.frame': 27 obs. of  9 variables:
  ..$ L1.1: num [1:27] 0.3 0.3 0.25 0.467 0.362 0.25 0.217 0.308 0.25 0.31 ...
  ..$ L1.2: num [1:27] 0.7 0.7 0.75 0.533 0.638 0.75 0.783 0.692 0.75 0.69 ...
  ..$ L2.1: num [1:27] 0.217 0.167 0.179 0.217 0.103 0.154 0.1 0.038 0.05 0.119 ...
  ..$ L2.2: num [1:27] 0.783 0.833 0.821 0.783 0.897 0.846 0.9 0.962 0.95 0.881 ...
  ..$ L3.1: num [1:27] 1 1 0.982 1 1 0.981 0.983 1 0.975 0.976 ...
  ..$ L3.2: num [1:27] 0 0 0.018 0 0 0.019 0.017 0 0.025 0.024 ...
  ..$ L4.1: num [1:27] 0.017 0.083 0.107 0.067 0.103 0.179 0.216 0.25 0.175 0.282 ...
  ..$ L4.2: num [1:27] 0.15 0.216 0.179 0.2 0.19 0.125 0.2 0.115 0.05 0 ...
  ..$ L4.3: num [1:27] 0.833 0.701 0.714 0.733 0.707 0.696 0.584 0.635 0.775 0.718 ...
 $ center    : Named num [1:9] 0.322 0.678 0.114 0.886 0.901 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "L1.1" "L1.2" "L2.1" "L2.2" ...
 $ pop.names : Named chr [1:27] "P01" "P02" "P03" "P04" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:27] "P01" "P02" "P03" "P04" ...
 $ all.names : Named chr [1:9] "EST-2*.098" "EST-2*.100" "G3PDH*.085" "G3PDH*.100" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "L1.1" "L1.2" "L2.1" "L2.2" ...
 $ loc.blocks: Named num [1:4] 2 2 2 3
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4"
 $ loc.fac   : Factor w/ 4 levels "EST-2*","G3PDH*",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
 $ loc.names : Named chr [1:4] "EST-2*" "G3PDH*" "IDHP-1*" "PGM-2*"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4"
 $ all.pop   :'data.frame': 9 obs. of  27 variables:
  ..$ P01: num [1:9] 0.3 0.7 0.217 0.783 1 0 0.017 0.15 0.833
  ..$ P02: num [1:9] 0.3 0.7 0.167 0.833 1 0 0.083 0.216 0.701
  ..$ P03: num [1:9] 0.25 0.75 0.179 0.821 0.982 0.018 0.107 0.179 0.714
  ..$ P04: num [1:9] 0.467 0.533 0.217 0.783 1 0 0.067 0.2 0.733
  ..$ P05: num [1:9] 0.362 0.638 0.103 0.897 1 0 0.103 0.19 0.707
  ..$ P06: num [1:9] 0.25 0.75 0.154 0.846 0.981 0.019 0.179 0.125 0.696
  ..$ P07: num [1:9] 0.217 0.783 0.1 0.9 0.983 0.017 0.216 0.2 0.584
  ..$ P08: num [1:9] 0.308 0.692 0.038 0.962 1 0 0.25 0.115 0.635
  ..$ P09: num [1:9] 0.25 0.75 0.05 0.95 0.975 0.025 0.175 0.05 0.775
  ..$ P10: num [1:9] 0.31 0.69 0.119 0.881 0.976 0.024 0.282 0 0.718
  ..$ P11: num [1:9] 0.308 0.692 0.154 0.846 0.962 0.038 0.154 0.038 0.808
  ..$ P12: num [1:9] 0.354 0.646 0.104 0.896 0.979 0.021 0.125 0.104 0.771
  ..$ P13: num [1:9] 0.317 0.683 0.167 0.833 0.8 0.2 0.033 0.716 0.251
  ..$ P14: num [1:9] 0.3 0.7 0.083 0.917 0.75 0.25 0.033 0.6 0.367
  ..$ P15: num [1:9] 0.46 0.54 0.14 0.86 0.74 0.26 0.04 0.62 0.34
  ..$ P16: num [1:9] 0.369 0.631 0.119 0.881 0.69 0.31 0 0.69 0.31
  ..$ P17: num [1:9] 0.494 0.506 0.104 0.896 0.747 0.253 0.003 0.659 0.338
  ..$ P18: num [1:9] 0.321 0.679 0.036 0.964 0.589 0.411 0 0.536 0.464
  ..$ P19: num [1:9] 0.286 0.714 0.086 0.914 0.871 0.129 0.129 0.343 0.528
  ..$ P20: num [1:9] 0.267 0.733 0.05 0.95 0.95 0.05 0.15 0.133 0.717
  ..$ P21: num [1:9] 0.241 0.759 0.121 0.879 0.966 0.034 0.138 0.103 0.759
  ..$ P22: num [1:9] 0.25 0.75 0.162 0.838 0.941 0.059 0.176 0.059 0.765
  ..$ P23: num [1:9] 0.339 0.661 0.054 0.946 0.893 0.107 0.125 0.089 0.786
  ..$ P24: num [1:9] 0.386 0.614 0.068 0.932 0.886 0.114 0.114 0.136 0.75
  ..$ P25: num [1:9] 0.308 0.692 0.115 0.885 0.823 0.177 0.135 0.01 0.855
  ..$ P26: num [1:9] 0.338 0.662 0.103 0.897 0.912 0.088 0.088 0.103 0.809
  ..$ P27: num [1:9] 0.353 0.647 0.074 0.926 0.941 0.059 0.059 0.118 0.823
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "genet" "list"
```

Comment: So far, I still do not know where the error is..I cannot find the difference between my work and the example above. It seems to be very similar but my data set. My data set is read from csv files and processed a little. It contains relatively small frequencies like 0. I cannot process the data with freq2genet. One error occurs as I said in my question..